# CSS Animation issue on Mozilla

Tags: html, css, slider

I want to use typewriter css animation in slider. Work well on chrome but does not work properly on Mozilla. Only work well one tour of slider(there is 4 slide). How can i fix this?

JS

```
            $this.css({display:'block'}).show(); // make sure slide shows
            $text1.css({left:'-30px', opacity:0,animation:'typing 2s steps(30,end))', display:'block', zIndex:'9'}).delay(100).animate({left:'0px', opacity:1, 100);
            $text2.css({left:'-30px', opacity:0, display:'block', zIndex:'9'}).delay(100).animate({left:'0px', opacity:1}, 100);
            $btn.css({opacity:0, display:'block', zIndex:'9'}).delay(3300).animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
            $image.css({marginTop:'30px', opacity:0, display:'block', zIndex:'1'}).delay(500).animate({marginTop:'0px',opacity:1}, 1000);
            $blurImg.css({marginTop:'30px', opacity:0, display:'block', zIndex:'2'}).delay(500).animate({marginTop:'0px',opacity:1}, 1000).animate({opacity:0}, 600, makeDisplayNone);
```

CSS

```
 @-webkit-keyframes typing {from { width:0; }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using is for Webkit browers only

You need to define the animation for `-moz` browser (firefox) as well AND the unprefixed version

```
@-moz-keyframes typing {from { width:0; }}

@keyframes typing {from { width:0; }}
```